# Which heroes can backdoor easily?

Tags: dota-2

Dota 2 has backdooring protection which makes it very hard to backdoor sometimes, unless you bring your whole team or best carries.

I did however see that some heroes can backdoor very easily, Meepo and Nature Prophet for example.

So the question is; which heroes in Dota 2 can solo backdoor fast and with ease?

Comment: Like you said, Nature's Prophet is the best, simply because he can bring his own creeps to the battle, and stop the tower regenerating, as well as being able to teleport next to the tower giving the enemy no time to stop you. :)

Comment: @Doomsknight Meepo is just as good because of his clones. I had fight against Meepo, he kept backdooring all the time and every time he would destroy towers and barracks in just a couple of seconds. So I'm wondering is there more heroes like those two. Pretty game-breaking if you ask me though.

Comment: I view it as a heros ability/strength. As opposed to game-breaking. Each hero is good at something. NP is a known great pusher. I'm interested in seeing meepo doing this. I can imagine how he does it, swapping out copies that are dieing, just never seen it done. I wouldnt say there are many if any more though, as it generally requires more than a single hero, to take the damage, and to deal it. Maybe chen. NP is definitely the best.

Comment: Chen most likely and any hero who can generate their own creeps - be it with helm of the dominator.

Comment: @Doomsknight Pretty sure only lane creeps remove backdoor protection, not summons. NP is good mainly because of his global teleport, and because he can push out lanes quickly using his treants (avoiding the need to get through backdoor protection in the first place).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, see [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29197/what-does-backdoor-mean-in-strategy-games-like-dota-or-lol) what backdooring actually is.

Tier 2, 3 and 4 towers and barracks have **backdoor protection**, which causes them to regenerate 90 hp per second and take only 25% damage from illusions if they are attacked without enemy creeps nearby.

So in order to backdoor successfully, a building needs to be low enough to be destroyed in a single hit, or the hero needs to be able to make more than 90 damage per second which after added damage reduction(armor) from tower which is ~ 55%-65% depending on the tier...you would need around **240 DPS** to make the minimum impact on the tower,and since enemy team will rush to stop you as soon as possible you will need a lot more damage.

This is generally very difficult for most heroes for most if not all of the game, with backdooring typically being a team effort,single-hit destruction or mostly beneficial ability or item on your hero.

Things to look for in a backdooring hero:

- **High DPS** - To overwhelm the BD protection you will need a lot of damage and attack speed, late in game many heroes can do it but earlier it makes for a big problem.
- **Mobility** - You will have to get to their base quickly as possible and/or unseen to avoid enemy team defending.
- **Summoned units** - They can be good way of backdooring since you don't have to put yourself in danger, but rarely have enough damage without hero contribution.
- **Items** - Boots of Travel, Shadowblade, Necronomicon, Manta Style, Helm of the Dominator, Mask of Madness or just a lot of pure DPS items.

Popular item choices to help you with this are **Desolator**(damage+armor reduction) and **Necronomicon** (DPS+extra creeps).

Some examples:

- **Nature's Prophet** - Teleport,spawn treants,DPS
- **Lycanthrope** - Very fast,DPS
- **Lone Druid** - Summoned bear deals a lot of damage to towers with his passive, DPS, tank
- **Leshrac** - Diabolic Edict deals huge damage to buildings if no nearby units
- **Clinkz** - Fast invisibility, DPS
- **Troll Warlord** - Only crazy DPS
- **Phantom Lancer** - Lots and lots of illusions, invisibility, DPS
- **Death Prophet** - Fast, ghosts can destroy buildings quickly
- **Broodmother** - Partial fast invisibility, broodlings, DPS
- **Meepo** - Can simultaneously defend and backdoor as needed using poof, DPS
- **Warlock** - Powerful golems that can tank and destroy
- **Faceless Void** - Chronosphere stops towers, DPS
- **Chaos Knight** - Fast, strong illusions, DPS
- **Tiny** - Huge damage, +75% to buildings with scepter
- **Shadow Shaman** - serpent wards
- **Chen** - Enchanted Creatures can tank and pack some DPS,depending which you take
- **Enchantress** - With DPS build and enchanted creatures to tank
- **Razor** - Eye of the storm does lots of DPS to towers since every hit reduces armor,with aghanims 2 storms can be active at the same time

Comment: Whisp is very useful if there is someone with good DPS in team.

Comment: Illusions will cancel backdooring protection? Btw I'll accept your answer, but if you think of more examples put them in. You can add Meepo in there too, because Iv'e seen him backdoor and destroy everything in a matter of seconds like a boss.

Comment: No,illusions are just a cheap way of doing a lot of extra damage and when you backdoor there won't be anyone around to quickly kill them as it is in combat.Yeah forgot meepo.

Comment: I added some to the answer. Illusions don't deal very good damage when backdooring, but they still contribute some.

Comment: Missing Chen (Enchanted Creatures, Tank with Heal), Enchantress (Enchanted Creatures, Tank with Heal, {might have DPS if made build that contains Hyperstone})

Comment: Might I just add, most heroes in this list, need  **a lot** of farm to backdoor this. Agility heroes with farm are the best ones to backdoor towers. Attack speed is what it's all about. Agility equals attack speed.

Answer (score 0):

I've been experimenting with Templar Assassin for backdooring. If you constantly put traps up around the lane you're pushing it can be impossible to gank her. This is especially true with items like blinkdagger, mask of madness, and boots of travel. Build enough damage to 2 shot the creep wave then refract all the damage the tower deals. Also she has insane dueling potential so the other team can't really send only one person back to defend.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent MANY hours doing actual tests to see which hero can actually backdoor a tower the fastest, while using a stopwatch to record the actual time it takes to backdoor. I have tried every viable hero along with different build configurations for each one and hands down the hero that can take down a tower the quickest is Alchemist, which is funny that he's not even mentioned in the list posted by someone else as people that are best at it. In fact Alchemist came in over 2 seconds quicker than the 2nd fastest hero with the best possible item configuration. For item configurations, I even tested combinations of items that you would never possibly get, although with alchemist his build is very viable nearly every game that doesn't end too early. Some of the other heroes I tested with item builds to get to 2-4 seconds longer than Alchemist had such ridiculous builds just to achieve that, it would never happen in a real match. The reason Alchemist is able to backdoor so much quicker than any other hero is because of his BAT being so much lower than any other hero, it allows him to hit towers much quicker than anyone else. I know most of you will say a hero like Troll Warlord hits faster, but keep in mind that Alchemist having the lowest BAT in the game means that nobody can ever hit as fast as him since there is an upper cap of how many times a hero can possibly hit in a second, and with Alchemist that is 5 hits per second. So even though his attack damage may not be as high as some other heroes, the fact that a tower can only regen 90 health per second and he can easily do over 5x's that amount of damage per second due to hit BAT with armor reduction, he wipes Tier4 towers out in 4.92 seconds with backdoor protection in place. If anyone is able to do a test where they can beat this time, I would like to know what hero you used and your item configuration because every other hero tested with ANY items, came in at slightly over 7 seconds at the lowest.

For anyone who responds, please do not give situational I think this would work feedback that you think would trump what I have already specifically tested. I would want real world tests done to prove this can be done any quicker than this by a single hero.

If anyone is curious about the build configuration I used, I could give the build if anyone is interested. It's viable for alchemist to achieve this build too since he can accumulate more gold than almost anyone else in the game, so no items are out of his reach.

Comment: Please post the build with your answer

Answer (score -1):

Razor can backdoor with aghs, refresh, deso, ac. Takes like 10 seconds though.